# networking problem

Tags: router

in our company. We would like to have 2 different subnet masks. 192.168.2.0/24 and 192.168.3.0/24. Could it be possible for the both subnet to communicate in a network? Need help. Thanks.

For example:
Lan 1:
Ip range:192.168.2.x
subnet:255.255.255.0

Lan 2:
Ip range:192.168.3.x
subnet:255.255.255.0

Could both lan communicate to each other?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Of course different subnets can communicate with each other. You just need at least one piece of hardware which is connected to both networks and which knows how to `route` traffic between them.

Usually this is done with a [router](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_(computing)), but if you do not have one available you could use a [multihomed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multihoming) PC.

It might be useful to read up on [this post on Server Fault Q&A](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work) to learn how IPv4 subnetting works. (especially the part "You can't get there from here").

However you already tagged your post [router](/questions/tagged/router), so you probably are aware that such a device exists. Which confused me since the question "Could both LANs communicate to each other?" and the answer (in the tag) are already next to each other. What was it *precisely* that you wanted to ask?

Comment: thank you sir for the reply. Yes we already have a router. What do i mean is, How does ip-range 192.168.2.0/24 and 192.168.3.0/24 be able to ping and communicate to each other? thanks a lot.

Comment: Which kind of router do you have? Different brands use different commands. Some you ssh into, some have a web interface. Please look up the model and add that to your post.

Comment: Our router is tp-link sir..

Comment: tp-link is a manufacturer who mostly makes SoHO devices. Q: Do you have a 'router' (and is so, which specific model) or a thing many people call router which actually is not a router but a many-in-one devices with modem+firewall+wirelessAccessPoint+switch... ?